# bootable windows usb with exe programs

Tags: windows, boot, usb

Once a year I format my dual booted hdd in order to use a "fresh" installation of vista. The rather annoying thing is that I have to install from scratch all programs that I use.

Is there a way to create a bootable usb stick, that will include the relevant `.exe` files?

The whole idea is to make an automated installation of windows side by side with the programs.

Comment: Why don't you just create an image of your hdd at a state your happy with?  There are dozens of third-party tools and tools provided by Microsoft to do this

Comment: @Ramhound: Thank you very much for your comment! Because it's something different. A restore point is not similar to a fresh install, isn't that right? :) And in case I want to make the install in another PC, the disk image won't apply...

Comment: I didn't suggest a restore point.  I suggested creating an image of the entire system state, which if used, would recover the system to said state.  A restore point can come close, but personal files are not deleted, and isn't what I am talking about.

Comment: Sorry, for the misunderstanding! Even so, a clean install is more straightforward than a disk image let alone that I won't be able to build the same system on an other computer.

Comment: You want to avoid installing the same programs. Creating a system image of your system with all your favorite programs, would avoid that, and why wouldn't you be able to restore that image on different hardware. I had a system I migrated to entirely different hardware without a single problem using this method.  The image was created within a single day, allowing me to pick up, like its exactly the same system.

Comment: To create a disk image it will take more time than to create a bootable usb. In addition I will need a second drive, with equal or higher capacity, if I choose to create an image. I still believe that having a usb stick is much easier and more straightforward!

Comment: You wanted to know what you wanted was possible, its not, what I describe requires very little storage.  If you do it as often as you claim you might want to consider it.

Comment: @Thanos An image is the *easiest and most straightforward* way to do what you want. There's a reason why many, many tools have been created and commercialized around that, and next to none about just installing *.exes from a flash drive.

Comment: @Ramhound Keep in mind that you have to sysprep a Windows image to reliably move it between hardware. There are certain configurations that are close enough that it will work, but it's not always as simple as imaging one disk, taking it to a different computer, and restoring the image.

Comment: @DarthAndroid I just used third-party software to do it.  The two systems didn't have a single thing in common

Comment: @DarthAndroid: My point is that when a disk is formatted, it's like new. However when it is "recovered" by an image, it's just a clone. I remember using images and restore points, but my system was never as it's been before. It was slower.

Comment: @Thanos It will be exactly the same speed as when you imaged it. You install the OS, immediately install all the programs you want, and then you image it. Unless you're comparing it to a system with an OS and *no* programs installed, then that image will always be the fastest, cleanest system with your programs installed. Restoring the image *will* format the disk like new. An image doesn't "recover" anything existing, it is *not* a restore point (in the Windows terminology).

Comment: @DarthAndroid: Thank you very much for the info's! Perhaps I am mistaken. Perhaps what I did in the past was to use a restore point, rather than a disk image. I think I'll post a new question about the differences in a clean and fresh install VS disk image. Could you post your previoius comment as an answer?

Comment: @Thanos - I attempted to explain I wasn't talking about a restore point, as I pointed out, a restore point often does not get rid of personal files since the restore point was made ( depending on their physical location ).  A restore point is more or less limited to the registry hive. My original suggestion involves creating an image of the entire hdd (smaller then you might think) once your system is in a state where you want it. As for the specific question many of these third-party tools can create an .exe like folder that does what you want but in the end work like a complete system image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is create a disk *image* after you install the OS, install your favorite programs, and get everything configured the way you like it (but before you do any serious use with the system).

This is different from a restore point, as the image actually creates a "snapshot" of the filesystem at the time the image is created. This image is stored separately (say, on an external drive), and when you restore it, the imaging tools will wipe/format the existing harddrive and then copy the image back to it. It will effectively "reset" the machine exactly back to how it was, including any perceived feel of speed. You will need to back up your personal files before restoring from the image and then restore your files afterwards.